# UISegmentedControl IOS7 hide border

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am having some graphical issues adapting my app to ios7. All my icons (color icons) now seem worse. They are completelly blue or grey depending where they are set.

Ok, I can assume that. But now, I have some problems with UISegmentedControl. they show a blue thiny line all around and I want to hide it. Just showing the image icon.

Is it possible?

Comment: Does `segmentedControl.layer.borderWidth`, `segmentedControl.layer.borderColor` help?

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed

Comment: segmentedControl.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill; Is it working  ?